# How to properly send data from APIClient in Django (rest_framework) for a POST request

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I've encountered some strange behavior in a Django unittest. Specifically, I'm using the APIClient module from rest_framework.test to simulate GET/POST requests from a unittest.

The issue occurs when updating/creating a new object in the Django ORM via a POST request (see the code below):

```
def test_something(self):
    data = {
        "name": 'unit testing',
        "data": {}
        }

    response = self.api_client.post(reverse('save_model'), data=data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def save_model(request):

    obj, created = MyModel.objects.update_or_create(
    user_id=request.user,
    **request.data
    )

    return JsonResponse({
        'id': obj.id,
        'name': obj.name,
        'user_id': obj.user_id.id
    })
```

The error i receive when running the test case:
**Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type**

Based on other stack posts involving this error, i would assume i have a type issue for the second parameter (the data field). However when the same exact data is used to store an object in Django shell, it works every time. Additionally, when the request is made from the client (with the same data) the request succeeds every time.

If i print the data in the unittest request i get the following:
(, u'{}')
(, u'unit testing')

Model code is below:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    data = JSONField()
```

So i thought this might be a unicode issue. But once again, storing the object with unicode data in the shell works just fine. One subtle difference to note, the django unittest will create a new test db for the models, whereas running in the shell does not.

Im out of answers, so if someone can shed some light on what's occuring here, that would be amazing.